# multiple parameters without knowing the argumen total ? (PHP functions as parameter topic)

Tags: php

Right now, i start to learn how to process PHP function as parameter and now i have function like this.

```
    function do_action($func_name) {
    if (func_num_args() <= 1) {
        return $func_name();
    } 

    $args = func_get_args();
    unset ($args[0]);        

    extract($args, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL , "foo");        
    return $func_name($foo_1, $foo_2);  //HERE ;)
}

echo do_action('time');
echo do_action('date', 'D, d F Y', 1267515462);
```

How to make this snippet of code has the ability to return and process multiple parameters without knowing the total of the argumen ? As you know it, date capable to process 2 parameter.

> date ( string $format [, int $timestamp ] )

And i want to broaden **do_action** to able to work without limit of total parameter. (See //HERE on the top code), it able to return every function as variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

**Edit:** Something like:

```
function do_action($func) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_shift($args); // removes the first element
    return call_user_func_array($func, $args); // magic!
}
```

Comment: thank you very much...you help me a lot.  i will check the reference of the function you give me ;D